# css menu text align

Tags: html, css

I need to align text to the center in this menu but I could not.

```
#mimenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3D2F2F;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#3d2f2f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top:10%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79epfyut/

Comment: Is it possible to add extra markups?

Comment: you have to set text-align to the parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your containing `li` a `display: table` element, and the anchor a `display: table-cell`.

That would allow you to easily set the `vertical-align` property of the anchor to `middle`:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/79epfyut/6/)

Although that changed a bit your visual style, and may require some adjusts...

**EDIT**

To keep the padding, set it on the container `li`: [**Fiddle with padding**](http://jsfiddle.net/79epfyut/7/)

Comment: But now the padding between items is gone. How would you get that back?

Comment: The solution is dealing to the specific problem of vertical aligment of the text... It solves *that* issue, and will be useful to someone else looking for the same problem... Although messed up with the style, I disagree with the downvote

Comment: And the padding may be set in the container `li`: http://jsfiddle.net/79epfyut/7/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a different approach i tried.

I am using the following CSS properties:

```
display: table; /*for main div*/ 

display: table-row; /*for ul */

display: table-cell; /*for li */
```

To make it much clear: 
[Fiddle here !](http://jsfiddle.net/jSVyY/77/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think this is a much easier solution. I hope you don't mind that I didn't use the same html layout that you did...but it does the same thing.Besides you should only really use unordered lists `<ul></ul>` for exactly that, and use `<div></div> <span></span>, etc` for ordering your layouts. Anyway, here's a simpler version of what you want to do: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QuietOmen/j06zozbL/)

Updated:

Sorry I'm at work so I was quickly trying to give an answer without taking up too much time to explain it...which likely isn't helpful. Anyway, here's the information on what I did.

Basically you take the outer div and assign it a class of menu. Give the parent div, or the menu in our case, a height and width. Then place each link in it's own div. These will be the children divisions.

The css for the children give them a percentage of the of the parent's width and 100% it's height. Make sure to make the display inline-block so they will be in a line and not stack on top of each other. OK so far I think everything is pretty easy to grasp from the css code, but here's the tricky part:

IN order to get the links to be vertically aligned you'll move them down by 50% of their parent's height...hence top: 50%. Then you need to adjust for their own height. You can do this by using transform: translateY(-50%); which moves the element up by 50% of it's own height. This is a very brief and you can read more from the article I initially read on the subject here: [Vertically Center Elements](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center)

And here's the code:

html:

```
<div id="menu">
 <div class="child">
    <a href="/joomla31/">Somos</a>
 </div>
 <div class="child">
    <a href="/joomla31/index.php/segunda-pagina">Segunda Página</a>
 </div>
 <div class="child">
    <a href="#">Este es un texto largo para el menú</a>
 </div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
#menu{
width: 100%;
height: 100px; 
display: block;
}
.child{
margin: 1%;
background-color:#3d2f2f; 
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
}
a{
background: #ffdb4c;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code or an explanation of what you did from the jsfiddle into the answer itself so that your answer is still useful when jsfiddle is down

Answer (score 0):

Dont give height and some property in a tag, you can give li only for that values.
Please refer:

```css
.miul
{
 font-size:10px;
 list-style:none;
 margin-left:-40px;
}
.miul li a
{
 text-decoration:none;
}

#sect_01
{
 width:100%;
 display:block;
}
/*
#mimenu ul
{
 list-style:none;
}

#mimenu li
{
 display:inline-block;
 color:white;
 font-size:14px;
 margin-right:10px
}

#mimenu  a
{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 25px 18px;
 display:block;
 background-color:#3d2f2f;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
*/
/*Menu */
#mimenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 
}

#mimenu ul li {
    float: left;
 color:white;
 font-size:14px;
  display:table;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #3D2F2F;
   margin-right:10px;
 margin-top:20px;
  background-color:#3d2f2f;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#mimenu  a {
    display: block;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 130px;  
    text-align:center;
    color:white; 
 
 
}

#top_menu a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}

#top_menu a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}

#top_menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}

#top_menu a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:960px;display:block;" id="mimenu">
<ul class="nav menu miul">
<li class="item-101 current active">
<a href="/joomla31/">Somos</a>
</li>
<li class="item-103">
<a href="/joomla31/index.php/segunda-pagina">Segunda Página</a>
</li>
<li class="item-104">
<a href="#">Este es un texto largo para el menú</a>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```